# Computing the infinitesimal generator of a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I want to compute the infinitesimal generator of the Markov chain associated with the following graph:

[image]

The transition matrix if the following:
$$ M = \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{matrix} \right) $$

Is it correct that the infinitesimal generator is the following matrix:

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \end{matrix} \right) $$

From $A = \lambda(M − I )$?

In other words, is $\lambda=1$? If so, why?

Comment: There are no such thing as an infinitesimal generator of a discrete-time Markov chain.

Comment: If you start with a discrete-time Markov chain $Y=(Y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with one-step transition matrix $M$, and a   unit-rate Poisson process $N=(N(t))_{t\ge 0}$ independent of $Y$, then the  process $X(t):=Y_{N(t)}$ is a continuous-time Markov chain with infinitesimal generator given by your matrix $A=M-I$.